# Why does it check in base class, while it is already pointing to the derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, virtual-functions, derived-class

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Derived; 

class Base { 
private: 
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base Fun"; }
}; 

class Derived: public Base { 
public: 
    void fun() { cout << "Derived Fun"; } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
Base *ptr = new Derived; 
ptr->fun(); 
return 0; 
}
```

The above function gives the error: 
`virtual void Base::fun()’ is private within this context`

But why does it need to check in the base class, while in the declaration we are making it clear that it's pointing to derived class?

Comment: does this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136606/if-a-private-virtual-function-is-overridden-as-a-public-function-in-the-derived?

Comment: Because `ptr` is a pointer to the *base* class.

Comment: What do you think the text `private:` within the class `Base` does????    Your code is using a pointer to `Base`, not a `Derived`.   So at the call point `ptr->fun()` knows that `fun()` is a private member of `Base` - and does not look at the *actual* type of the object that `ptr` points at.

Comment: Now think about what the meaning of your code is supposed to be, aside from how it technically works. A method in a base class says that all children have this kind of method. If it is a private one, it is meant to be used internally. So what would the meaning of making it public be? I don't see one. Also, how would a child know something that is private in the base? Note that it is private, not protected. Third thing, you should really use the `override` keyword.

Comment: `while in the declaration we are making it clear that it's pointing to derived class?` no the declaration is `Base *ptr = …` so you create a pointer to `Base`. The compiler checks if it is valid to assign the pointer returned by `new Derived` to `ptr`, but that does not change the fact that it is still a pointer to `Base`. So all compiler checks for `ptr->…` are done assuming it is a pointer to Base,  resolving the correct virtual function is done at runtime.